# multiple submit button

Tags: forms

I have two submit buttons in two field .
My problem is that if I press ENTER from the field 2 of textfield , Submit 1  gets triggered instead of trigger submit 2.
but submit handler works perfectly for both submit button when it is clicked.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501890/handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-drupal-form-api

Comment: i tried that too,but not getting.

Answer (score 0):

This is native browser functionality, you are going to need to use JavaScript to circumvent and add your own behavior